# How the handset manufacturer set the DPI on android OS?

Tags: android, dpi

If I am the handset manufacturer and I have the handset with 5.0 inch and 1920*1080 resolution , **how I set the DPI ?**

I can calculate the generalized density like this:

**Actual_density** = root(1920*1920+1080*1080)/5.0 = 440.5 dpi

And then get the **generalized density** :xxhdpi

Of course , I can get the constant value of the **DENSITY_XXHIGH** :480

So , should I set the DPI to 480 dpi ? And how to set it ?

Is it important to set the DPI ?

Thanks .

Comment: Dear @hackbod, how do you think about this question ? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it in `/system/build.prop` , dpi is defined as `ro.sf.lcd_density`

```
$ cat /system/build.prop | grep lcd
ro.sf.lcd_density=240
```

Yes, it's important to set the correct dpi. If not your device will have problems in play store, and the display will look ugly.

Comment: Thanks. By the way , should I set the DPI to 480 as the question ? Am i right ?

Comment: Dear @Binoy Babu, If I don't set the DPI , is there any problem ? Thanks .

Comment: If you don't use correct dpi the display will look blurry with large icons and all.

Comment: Should I set the DPI to 480 as the question ? Am i right ? @Binoy Babu . Thank very much .

Comment: Do you know whether there are related documents about to how to set the DPI value by handset manufacturer？ @ Binoy Babu